# Digital Control Engineering book recommendations

Tags: control, control-system, books

What are good books on digital control engineering specifically? I'm a third year electrical/computer engineering student who will be doing a course on digital control next semester, but would like to get a head start.

Comment: I don't see how this question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/7796/book-recommendations-for-digital-circuit-design?rq=1 is any different and didn't get down-voted.

Comment: There are dozens of similar questions about book recommendations in other fields and plenty with quite a few up-votes. A simple search for 'book recommendations' above will confirm this. Please be more consistent with what you flag as opinion based. Your current actions are quite hypocritical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sad about the down-votes, people should be encouraged to seek enlightenment - however you should show what attempts/similar textbooks you've seen/looked for already.

During my robotics engineering degree, I used the following textbooks and I recommend them:

Contro Systems Engineering by Nise, for mostly Classical control (not quite digital, but very important to understand first)

Robot Modelling and Control by Spong et al. 
This one is very good for modern control theory with digital systems, and state-space feedback which is the next step up from classical PID style control. Pretty sure it also has Riccatti style Linear Quadratic Regulator control (LQR) in there.

You may want to find a more practical 'hands on' control theory textbook that actually implements fully, with ARM Cortex processors and C code examples, the control theory shown in the usual textbooks. You may find it a bit ambiguous as to the step to take a nice control gain matrix and actually make it into a workable program running on an embedded system.

I know that Texas Instruments have some ARM Cortex dev boards as platforms used by at least one textbook with fully worked examples for control, including the use of real-time operating system kernels.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate taking time to respond. I've just finished a course on continuous control and actually have the book you recommended (by Nise) in addition to Modern Control Engineering. Are you referring to Embedded Systems: Real-Time Operating Systems for Arm Cortex M Microcontrollers for the more hands on book? It looks great :) Will check out the Robot Modelling and Control book too.

Comment: @O.Powell yeah man, the embedded systems textbook I think that is the one. There is a course at my uni which I tutor, that is moving on to that book and the TI Eval boards for teaching students digital control (motor drives etc)

Comment: Thanks. Just a quick comment about what you said with regard to me not demonstrating any attempts at trying to find a suitable book. If you simply search for "book recommendations" on here, you will find plenty of examples of questions virtually identical to mine for other fields, with no mention of attempts at trying to find books first. Many have quite a few up-votes too. That's why I assumed it was ok to pose the question as I did. If this is the sort of attitude towards people seeking reading material, then I will no longer bother with this site.

Comment: I agree with you. I don't agree with them down voting your question.